# Lyx can no longer find images

Tags: floats, errors, lyx

I have update a number of images in lyx and changed the contents of images but not their path. I import images as follows:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Figure_name_1}\caption{Figure description}
\end{figure}
```

After I changed the figure with another but with the same name lyx gives the error:

```
Latex error: File 'Figure_name_1' not found.
```

But the figure is in the same directory as it was before when it worked.

Comment: Open task manager and look if there is any instance of pdflatex or something like this running.

Comment: If you exit LyX and reopen does it now work? If not, can you upload a minimal example? I cannot reproduce. For more information please see https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Comment: I did try that and it didn't work. The problem was that there were dots in the name of the image file. It works if they are escaped using \lyxdot.

Comment: Sounds like you solved your problem, could you write up a proper answer?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved in comments